# Card set the same height of a card in Vue JS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

So i have a card component:

```
<div
      name="card container"
      class="flex max-w-[25vw] flex-grow flex-col gap-3 rounded-xl border-2 border-green-600 transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105"
    >
      <div name="image" class="flex h-[30vh] justify-center p-2 align-middle">
        <img :src="getImageUrl()" :alt="imageDesc" />
      </div>
      <div
        name="web architecture"
        class="ml-3 w-fit rounded-3xl border-2 px-3 font-semibold"
        :class="templateColor"
      >
        {{ webArchitecture }}
      </div>
      <div
        name="card title"
        class="flex-grow-1 border-2 border-blue-600 text-center text-xl font-bold"
      >
        {{ title }}
      </div>

      <div
        name="card description"
        class="flex h-fit justify-center overflow-y-auto border-2 border-red-600 p-4 text-center align-middle font-semibold text-gray-500"
      >
        {{ description }}
      </div>
</div>
```

and then i import card to another container and i use it:

```
<div
    class="flex-0 container mx-auto mt-5 flex items-stretch justify-center gap-5 rounded-xl border-2 border-purple-600 p-5"

... multiple cards compoent...

</div>
```

and the cards dont have the same height. I tried flex-grow, overflow-y-auto and some on but it doesnt work. Anyone has a clue how to make it work?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a sandbox and it works just fine https://play.tailwindcss.com/H6UVbLPkLI.
I did have to add a closing `>` to the surrounding div.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out https://play.tailwindcss.com/AoGooIJ9CT (Solution)

```
    <div class="flex-0 container mx-auto mt-5 flex items-start justify-center gap-5 rounded-xl border-2 border-purple-600 p-5">
  <div name="card container" class="flex max-w-[25vw] flex-grow flex-col gap-3 rounded-xl border-2 border-green-600 transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105">
    <div name="image" class="flex h-[30vh] justify-center p-2 align-middle">
      <img :src="getImageUrl()" :alt="imageDesc" />
    </div>
    <div name="web architecture" class="ml-3 w-fit rounded-3xl border-2 px-3 font-semibold" :class="templateColor">{{ webArchitecture }}</div>
    <div name="card title" class="flex-grow-1 border-2 border-blue-600 text-center text-xl font-bold">{{ title }}</div>

    <div name="card description" class="flex h-fit justify-center overflow-y-auto border-2 border-red-600 p-4 text-center align-middle font-semibold text-gray-500">{{ description }}</div>
  </div>
  <div name="card container" class="flex max-w-[25vw] flex-grow flex-col gap-3 rounded-xl border-2 border-green-600 transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105">
    <div name="image" class="flex h-[30vh] justify-center p-2 align-middle">
      <img :src="getImageUrl()" :alt="imageDesc" />
    </div>
    <div name="web architecture" class="ml-3 w-fit rounded-3xl border-2 px-3 font-semibold" :class="templateColor">{{ webArchitecture }}</div>
    <div name="card title" class="flex-grow-1 border-2 border-blue-600 text-center text-xl font-bold">{{ title }}</div>

    <div name="card description" class="flex h-fit justify-center border-2 border-red-600 p-4 text-center align-middle font-semibold text-gray-500">{{ descriptio sfaf safdafaf ssdfsgf sdgsdgf sdfsgsf sdgsdf sdgsfsdgfsdgfsdfsgf }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```